# Does a .ForEach loop block when there are no more threads available

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

We have a `.ForEach` loop (TPL) which starts many, many, many Tasks.
Since the TPL is consuming threads from the thread pool I am wondering what will happen when there are no more threads available?
Will the calling code block until threads are available again?

I know the threadpool has a global work queue where work items (`Task`) will be queued. Can that queue ever be full?

Our problem is that some of the tasks are long running (30 minutes) and some are short (a second), but we have thousands of such Tasks, if not more. Does the TPL start a new Thread for each Task I start? I think not. At what point will the thread pool be exhausted?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When there are no more free Threads there are several algorithms kicking in. Yhe main one is that the ThreadPool will slowly create extra threads (max 2/second).

This helps to address your situation with long-running tasks, but the system is not perfect. Be ware of a situation where hundreds of threads are created, your app will probably crash.

First approach would be to specify a DegreeOfParallelism on the ForEach. You want to limit the number of threads to `numberOfCores * someFactor` where someFactor depends on the I/O the Tasks perform.

You could also investigate custom TPL schedulers, I don't know much about that.

Comment: Good thing you used a smiley. The default MaxThreads is insanely high and you don't want to mess with it.

Comment: I don't think you truly responded to the question of the OP. "Can that queue ever be full?" the response should be No (technically if you exhaust the memory of the computer, or the 2gb limit on some array, but we will ignore it), "At what point will the thread pool be exhausted?" ThreadPool will create only MaxThreads threads. After that your new Tasks will all be enqueued waiting for a free thread.

Comment: Thanks. The tasks will be queued, yes, but what will happen to the calling code? Will it block because there are no threads?

Comment: John, the calling code always blocks on a Parallel.ForEach(), that lets you wrap it in a try/catch for instance. Run it from a separate Task if you want to free up the main thread.

Comment: @John To make an example of what Henk told you, try this in a Console Application: `Parallel.ForEach(new[] { 1 }, p => Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite));` and see if it exits.

Comment: @Henk, if I start a seperate Task containing the .ForEach the Tasks therein would not go to the global queue, but to the parent task's local queue, according to MSDN. Would this be a problem?

Comment: John, good question. I think it will just work (work-stealing between queues) but I never dealt with large numbers of long Tasks. Worst-case you run it from an old fashioned Thread.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Be aware of a situation where hundreds of threads are created, your app will probably crash." please? Is it related to an `OutOfMemoryException` or has a large amount of `Task`s actually crashed a program of yours for another reason?

Comment: @Jonathan - Mainly memory (1 MB / Thread). On 32bits you'll never reach maxThreads. A large amount of (queued) Tasks is usually quite OK.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks, because I am creating a massive amount of tasks for my current project :).

Comment: @Henk: the tasks we are creating are long running because of the I/O (database) is quite extensive. It's not CPU time that they are using up but the network. Should or can those types of tasks run on a threadpooled thread or rather a dedicated thread? Thanks.

Comment: John, a dedicated Thread would _not_ help at all. Tasks could be a little smarter about I/O (and re-using the Thread), I don't know. Everything points to putting a cap on it, the question is how many to allow.